# Post on a company facebook page wall on behalf of a user

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a wp7 app that connect with facebook and lets assume i have the users access token

I am wondering if it is possible to write on the wall of some company facebook page as the user. (i have no ownership of the facebook page and not affiliated with it in any way)

If it is, do you know which permission do i need to obtain ? would love to get any kind of code snippet  or a direction i should follow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to write on the wall on behave of the user. You always get a token in the context of a Facebook application - so it will be the app posting on the wall, not the user. And the maximum permission app can ask a user for is [publish_stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NginR.png) which allows you (your app actually) to:

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends.

so in order to post to the company wall, you need to:

1. Request publish_stream permission from the user
2. Issue a post request to https://graph.facebook.com/<>/feed url with your message

It's really easy to test. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, click on "Get access token", select "publish_stream" permission in "Extended" tab, set action to POST, enter "LGUSA/feed" into URL field, click on "Add a field", enter "message: test" and click POST. You will get ID of your post back. See screenshot attached [image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for the answer, so i dont exactly understand yet what are my limitations, according to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335290/how-to-post-image-on-facebook-fan-page-using-c-sharp-facebook-sdk-on-codeplex it seems possible to post on a fan page wall. so whats the difference ? forgive me as i am not very familiar with the facebook jargon whats the difference between feed and a wall ?

Comment: looking at LGUSA page i see what is a feed, now i'm not sure i understand where is the wall. so, if i want to complain to LGUSA about a broken TV, i would write it on the feed ?

Comment: yes - feed is the stream of messages appearing on the wall. Also - i think you are confused - I said that it IS possible to post on the wall and provided the way to do it from FB Graph API tool. You can do exactly the same from the C# code. First sentence of my answer just clarifies that the post will be from the app acting on behave of the user, not from the user directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is going to be a bit vauge, but here goes:

- First the user is going to have to be authenticated to facebook. There is a good example [here](https://github.com/offbysome/Facebook-WP7-Login-Button). This will give you an authentication tolken to allow you to interact with the API.
- The user is going to need facebook permissions to write to the wall. Facebook permissions are described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). I don't know about the specifics of your problem, but with more details I may be able to help more.
- then you shoud be able to post to the appropiate wall using the facebook [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) (you'll probably need to be signed up to facebook with a developer account to get to this page).